# Apache POI, changing File Mime Type. It's possible to Fix it?

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx

I'm having problems with Apache POI and File Mime Type. 
I Use a file template (Microsoft Word DOCX) to modify some values with Apache Poi.
The original file has the mime type "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" (in linux: file -i {filename}), but and I process the file with POI and save then again I got "application/octet-stream" and I wish to Keep the File with the original mime type.

I open the file with HEX editor, both files original and modified and both has the same "magical numbers" (50 4B 03 04), but the file size is different, even when the texts are the same.
So It's possible to fix it? Anyone have the same problem? I check it in LibreOffice and appears to have same behavior of Apache POI.

Any help, any information will help.

Comment: Does Apache Tika manage to detect the file type correctly? If so, sounds like a bug in your version of the `file` tool

Comment: I parse the Document and send to another third party API and they don't accept docx with different mime type, should be "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document".
But how it's possible to manipulate/parse the Document and keep this mime type?
I try in windows too and I got same problem.

Comment: The mime type of an OOXML file is set by the `[Content_Types.xml]` file embedded within the zip structure. Apache POI sets that correctly. Any software that doesn't check that is doing it wrong and needs pointing to the Microsoft spec!

Comment: Very interesting! 
I check the files, both are similar, but not equals. The order, indentation of elements are different. 
I really not sure why stop works in linux and windows file system.

Comment: If you are sending to a 3rd party API, is that over HTTP. Then you can set the Content-Type HTTP header. I'm not familiar with O/S file systems that support setting mime types on files (`file -i` just says regular file on my Mac).

Comment: Some specs of OOXML file packing:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Packaging_Conventions

Comment: I have made a test here. We unzip the DOCX file and repack again in windows with 7zip and the mime type is just fine (using DEFLATE method).
We do the same repack using 7zip using BZIP2 and the mime type appears to be "application/zip".

So the problem is the method that Apache POI and LibreOffice uses to Packing the file.

Answer (score 1):

As you already stated in a comment, the kind how Apache POI rearranges the Office Open XML `ZIP` package leads to misinterpreting the content type by some tools. An Office Open XML file (`*.docx`, `*.xlsx`, `*.pptx`) **is** a `ZIP` archive but somewhat how `Microsoft Office` is packing that archive must be special. I have not found what exactly it is though.

Example:

Start having a `Document.docx` having some simple content, which was saved by Microsoft Word.

For this, `file -i` produces:

```
axel@arichter:~/Dokumente/JAVA/poi/poi-4.0.1$ file -i Document.docx 
Document.docx: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document; charset=binary
```

Now run that code:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;

public class WordReadAndReWrite {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  String inFilePath = "Document.docx";
  String outFilePath = "NewDocument.docx";

  XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(inFilePath));

  doc.createParagraph().createRun().setText("new text inserted");

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outFilePath); 
  doc.write(out);
  out.close();
  doc.close();
 }

}
```

For the resulting `NewDocument.docx`,  `file -i` produces:

```
axel@arichter:~/Dokumente/JAVA/poi/poi-4.0.1$ file -i NewDocument.docx 
NewDocument.docx: application/octet-stream; charset=binary
```

But if we are doing the same without using Apache POI's [ZipPackage](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/openxml4j/opc/ZipPackage.html) but instead using [FileSystem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html) for getting the `XML` out of the Office Open XML `ZIP` package using following code:

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.FileSystem;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;

import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;

public class WordReadAndReWriteFileSystem {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  String inFilePath = "Document.docx";
  String outFilePath = "NewDocument.docx";

  FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystems.newFileSystem(Paths.get(inFilePath), null);
  Path wordDocumentXml = fileSystem.getPath("/word/document.xml");

  DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
  Document xmlDocument = documentBuilder.parse(Files.newInputStream(wordDocumentXml, StandardOpenOption.READ));

  Node p = xmlDocument.createElement("w:p");
  Node r = xmlDocument.createElement("w:r");
  p.appendChild(r);
  Node t = xmlDocument.createElement("w:t");
  r.appendChild(t);
  Node text = xmlDocument.createTextNode("new text inserted");
  t.appendChild(text);

  Node body = xmlDocument.getElementsByTagName("w:body").item(0);
  Node sectPr = xmlDocument.getElementsByTagName("w:sectPr").item(0);
  body.insertBefore(p, sectPr);

  TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
  Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
  DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(xmlDocument);
  Path tmpDoc = Files.createTempFile("wordDocument", "tmp");
  tmpDoc.toFile().deleteOnExit();
  StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(Files.newOutputStream(tmpDoc, StandardOpenOption.WRITE));
  transformer.transform(domSource, streamResult);

  fileSystem.close();

  Path tmpZip = Files.createTempFile("zipDocument", "tmp");
  tmpZip.toFile().deleteOnExit();
  Path path = Files.copy(Paths.get(inFilePath), tmpZip, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
  fileSystem = FileSystems.newFileSystem(path, null);
  wordDocumentXml = fileSystem.getPath("/word/document.xml");

  Files.copy(tmpDoc, wordDocumentXml, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
  fileSystem.close();

  Files.copy(tmpZip, Paths.get(outFilePath), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

 }

}
```

Then for the resulting `NewDocument.docx`,  `file -i` produces:

```
axel@arichter:~/Dokumente/JAVA/poi/poi-4.0.1$ file -i NewDocument.docx 
NewDocument.docx: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document; charset=binary
```

Answer (score 0):

This Code shows the correct mime type of file for all files that I test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String fileName = "model_libreoffice.docx";
//        String fileName = "model_poi.docx";
//        String fileName = "model_msoffice.docx";
//        String fileName = "model_repacked_bz2.docx";

    try {
        InputStream is = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/" + fileName);
        Tika t = new Tika();
        String mime = t.detect(is, fileName);
        System.out.println("----> "  + mime);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

After long debugging and testing I think that's problem with Third party validation of files.
This simple code shows me the correct mime type for all files that I try, modified by MicrosoftOffice, LibreOffice, Apache Poi, Unzip and Zipping again (renamed to DOCX) the content files of DOCX...

So I think that's problem can be mark as "solved" at all.